# How to make a Dialog to be a child of a widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, provider

I have struggled to access data from a `Provider` in a `Dialog` widget. But i got a general ERROR from `Provider`.

After I took a look at the widget tree I saw that the `Dialog` widget was the child of `Material` widget not the child of the widget from I am showing it.

So the error is wright: I don't have any `Provider` above my `SilverList Widget`.

My question is: Can I make somehow the `Dialog` widget to be the child of my widget, where (ofcourse) the provided information is accessible?

**EDIT 1:**

I am already passing the context of the widget parent to the `showDialog()` builder method:

[image]

Comment: shares the context of the parent widget to Dialog. I think it should work.

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean..

Comment: every widget has a context variable in its build method. And when creating a dialog, I could pass or send this context variable as a parameter and use it to create the dialog. I'll try to send you a reply later.

Comment: As I understand it, this problem is with the Provider. I have never used the Provider, but I imagine that it may be being removed from memory before use or it is not being started. You could add the error message as it makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't understand well how the widget tree build the drawer. A drawer is build as a new screen so it will be at the same level with the screen where I pushed from the drawer.

The `provider` can be seen just down in widget tree, and not at the same level.

So the solution was to move `Provider` widget in the `main.dart` right after `MaterialApp`.